# Change keyframes values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this piece of css but I want to change the width in the keyframe with a variable in javascript. How can I do that?

```css
@keyframes test {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be a keyframe animation? Typically you would use the CSS `transition` property for this kind of animation powered by JavaScript, like this:

```js
var width = 50;

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  width += 50;
  document.getElementById('box').style.width = `${width}px`;
});
```

```css
#box {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: width .5s;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>

<button id="button">Change Width</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked perfectly! You were right, it didn't have to be a keyframe animation. I'm a beginner and that was the only way I knew how to animate something.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a more general animation (that can't be encompassed by just doing a transition) then you can use JS to set a CSS variable.

Taking the example in the question, replace the 100% with a variable:

```
@keyframes test {
  100% {
    width: var(--bg);
  }
}
```

and the Javascript you'd have something like:

```
thediv.style.setProperty('--bg', '60px');
```

Answer (score 1):

@JohnUleis already answeared correctly. I was too late. But I add just for fun a solution. Is named: **How far is Rom?** ;-)

Cheers

```js
let root = document.documentElement;
const div = document.querySelector('div');
root.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  div.style.setProperty('--width', e.clientX + "px");
  div.innerHTML = e.clientX + ' km';
});
```

```css
:root {
  --width: 100%; 
}

div {
  background: hotpink;
  width: var(--width);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>how far is rom?</div>
```

Comment: All ways lead to Rome!

Comment: @four-eyes I see you know oder besser: Ick sehe du weßt bescheid ;-)